# Parameter dependent constructor of templated class

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to create templated class where constructor implementation depends on the parameter value. I wanna do it with separate implementations as the number of constructor arguments and initiations will be different. It needs to be divided into h/cpp files to hide implementation.

My current implementation is following:

main:

```cpp
#include "class.h"

int main()
{
    MyStruct<MyEnum::One> c1(0);
    MyStruct<MyEnum::Two> c2;
    return 0;
}
```

class.h:

```cpp
enum class MyEnum {One, Two};

template <MyEnum T>
class MyStruct {
    public:
    template<bool Q = T == MyEnum::One>
    explicit MyStruct(int i, typename std::enable_if_t<Q>* = 0);
    
    template<bool Q = T == MyEnum::One>
    explicit MyStruct(typename std::enable_if_t<!Q>* = 0);
};
```

class.cpp:

```cpp
#include "class.h"

template <MyEnum T>
template<bool Q>
MyStruct<T>::MyStruct(int i, typename std::enable_if_t<Q>*)  { }
    
template <MyEnum T>
template<bool Q>
MyStruct<T>::MyStruct(typename std::enable_if_t<!Q>*)  { }

template class MyStruct<MyEnum::One>;
template class MyStruct<MyEnum::Two>;
```

The problem is with the linking (msvc x64 native v19.29), linker says there is no symbols found for the constructors. This means the explicit instantiation doesn't work properly.

Errors:

```
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl MyStruct<0>::MyStruct<0><1>(void *)" (??$?0$00@?$MyStruct@$0A@@@QEAA@PEAX@Z) referenced in function main
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl MyStruct<1>::MyStruct<1><0>(void *)" (??$?0$0A@@?$MyStruct@$00@@QEAA@PEAX@Z) referenced in function main
run.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

How to make it work? I am constrained to std 17.
If I move the implementation to header everything works ok but I need to hide the implementation in precompiled object due to IP safety.

Comment: I didn't understand your requirement. What should happen if I pass some random class to the template parameter?

Comment: What version of msvc are you using?
I can't seem to reproduce: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/W4668de7z

Comment: please include the error message in the question.

Comment: The constructors are not instantiated (and AFAICT you cannot explicitly instantiate such constructors).

Comment: @kiner_shah this template accept non-type parameters, values of type MyEnum. You cannot pass here anything else.

Comment: @ShadowMitia I added the compiler version in description (msvc x64 native v19.29). This is strange that in godbolt it works fine like in a header only version.

Comment: Explicit instantiation of the class instantiates all its non-template members, but cannot instantiate members that are themselves templates - there's generally no way to determine their parameters.

Comment: I though the default bool value in constructor should cover it as it do in header only version

Comment: In header-only version, the definition of the template is available to the compiler at the point it's used, so the compiler instantiates one as needed. If you want to rely on explicit instantiation instead, you have to manually spell out each instantiation of the constructor you want to be usable.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than playing games with `enable_if`, consider explicit specializatiion. Along these lines:

```
// class.h

template <MyEnum T>
class MyStruct {
public:
    explicit MyStruct();
};

// class.cpp

template <> MyStruct<MyEnum::One>::MyStruct() {
  // implementation here
}

template <> MyStruct<MyEnum::Two>::MyStruct() {
  // implementation here
}

// This is not necessary for the two consturctors,
// but perhaps you have other members to instantiate.
template class MyStruct<MyEnum::One>;
template class MyStruct<MyEnum::Two>;
```

Comment: Ok, this is the right answer for my original question. I simplified the code too much. In the real situation my constructors has different arguments so they can not share the same constructor declaration.

Comment: Well then, I suppose you should show an example that actually demonstrates the problem you are having.

Comment: You are right. I put there an int argument in one constructor.

Comment: `MyStruct<0, MyEnum::One> c1;` won't compile. `MyStruct` only has one template parameter, not two.

Comment: Ohhh... That is right. Fixed.

Comment: So the client code does not need to use `MyStruct` generically? As in `template <MyEnum T> foo() { MyStruct<T> bar; }` Then a) I wonder why it's a template and not two separate named non-template classes, but b) if you insist on it being a template, just specialize the whole `MyStruct`

Comment: Yes. The from the user's perspective it is not a generic template, only few possibilities already compiled are available for him. The reason of doing this in a templated class is performance and minimizing of the code size. It is going to be implemented in a large high performance class code where is a lot of statically resolved ifs, arguments and returned values are dependent on the template parameter. But the general algorithm is the same. My previous implementation was indeed the specialization but it looks horrible so I decided to check if I can improve it.

Comment: My current solution according to @IgorTandetnik comments is to move the definition of constructors to header file, and call from them the private functions that implements the logic and can be defined in cpp. The proposed explicit instantiation is is enough in such a case. I will post the answer if this post will be reopened.